# sqoop job prompt password for every second execution in oozie

Tags: sqoop, cloudera-cdh, oozie-coordinator

Hi i have created the sqoop job with incremental import and scheduled with oozie after configuring sqoop-site.xml for saving password within the meta-store the sqoop job in the oozie workflow after being scheduled it runs successfully for the first execution and it prompt password for the second execution in the oozie and it gets killed because of prompting the password.so please help to solving the issue

Sqoop command:

```
job -exec job10 --meta-connect "jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:16000/sqoop"
```

sqoop-site.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<!--
Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
distributed with this work for additional information
regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
"License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
software distributed under the License is distributed on an
"AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
specific language governing permissions and limitations
under the License.
-->

<!-- Put Sqoop-specific properties in this file. -->

<configuration>

  <!--
    Set the value of this property to explicitly enable third-party
    ManagerFactory plugins.

    If this is not used, you can alternately specify a set of ManagerFactories
    in the $SQOOP_CONF_DIR/managers.d/ subdirectory.  Each file should contain
    one or more lines like:
      manager.class.name[=/path/to/containing.jar]

    Files will be consulted in lexicographical order only if this property
    is unset.
  -->
  <!--
  <property>
    <name>sqoop.connection.factories</name>
    <value>com.cloudera.sqoop.manager.DefaultManagerFactory</value>
    <description>A comma-delimited list of ManagerFactory implementations
      which are consulted, in order, to instantiate ConnManager instances
      used to drive connections to databases.
    </description>
  </property>
  -->

  <!--
    Set the value of this property to enable third-party tools.

    If this is not used, you can alternately specify a set of ToolPlugins
    in the $SQOOP_CONF_DIR/tools.d/ subdirectory.  Each file should contain
    one or more lines like:
      plugin.class.name[=/path/to/containing.jar]

    Files will be consulted in lexicographical order only if this property
    is unset.
  -->
  <!--
  <property>
    <name>sqoop.tool.plugins</name>
    <value></value>
    <description>A comma-delimited list of ToolPlugin implementations
      which are consulted, in order, to register SqoopTool instances which
      allow third-party tools to be used.
    </description>
  </property>
  -->

  <!--
    By default, the Sqoop metastore will auto-connect to a local embedded
    database stored in ~/.sqoop/. To disable metastore auto-connect, uncomment
    this next property.
  -->
  <!--
  <property>
    <name>sqoop.metastore.client.enable.autoconnect</name>
    <value>false</value>
    <description>If true, Sqoop will connect to a local metastore
      for job management when no other metastore arguments are
      provided.
    </description>
  </property>
  -->

  <!--
    The auto-connect metastore is stored in ~/.sqoop/. Uncomment
    these next arguments to control the auto-connect process with
    greater precision.
  -->

  <property>
    <name>sqoop.metastore.client.autoconnect.url</name>
    <value>jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:16000/sqoop</value>
    <description>The connect string to use when connecting to a
      job-management metastore. If unspecified, uses ~/.sqoop/.
      You can specify a different path here.
    </description>
  </property>
<!--
 <property>
    <name>sqoop.metastore.client.autoconnect.username</name>
    <value>SA</value>
    <description>The username to bind to the metastore.
    </description>
  </property>
-->
  <property>
    <name>sqoop.metastore.client.autoconnect.password</name>
    <value>cloudera</value>
    <description>The password to bind to the metastore.
    </description>
  </property>


  <!--
    For security reasons, by default your database password will not be stored in
    the Sqoop metastore. When executing a saved job, you will need to
    reenter the database password. Uncomment this setting to enable saved
    password storage. (INSECURE!)
  -->

  <property>
    <name>sqoop.metastore.client.record.password</name>
    <value>true</value>
    <description>If true, allow saved passwords in the metastore.
    </description>
  </property>


  <!--
    Enabling this option will instruct Sqoop to put all options that
    were used in the invocation into created mapreduce job(s). This
    become handy when one needs to investigate what exact options were
    used in the Sqoop invocation.
  -->
  <!--
  <property>
    <name>sqoop.jobbase.serialize.sqoopoptions</name>
    <value>true</value>
    <description>If true, then all options will be serialized into job.xml
    </description>
  </property>
  -->

  <!--
    SERVER CONFIGURATION: If you plan to run a Sqoop metastore on this machine,
    you should uncomment and set these parameters appropriately.

    You should then configure clients with:
       sqoop.metastore.client.autoconnect.url =
       jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://&lt;server-name&gt;:&lt;port&gt;/sqoop
  -->
  <!--
  <property>
    <name>sqoop.metastore.server.location</name>
    <value>/tmp/sqoop-metastore/shared.db</value>
    <description>Path to the shared metastore database files.
    If this is not set, it will be placed in ~/.sqoop/.
    </description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>sqoop.metastore.server.port</name>
    <value>16000</value>
    <description>Port that this metastore should listen on.
    </description>
  </property>
  -->

</configuration>
```

workflow.xml:

```
workflow-app name="My_Workflow" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.5">
    <start to="sqoop-32f8"/>
    <kill name="Kill">
        <message>Action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>
    <action name="sqoop-32f8">
        <sqoop xmlns="uri:oozie:sqoop-action:0.2">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <command>job -exec job10 --meta-connect &quot;jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:16000/sqoop&quot;</command>
        </sqoop>
        <ok to="hive-2a53"/>
        <error to="Kill"/>
    </action>
    <action name="hive-2a53" cred="hcat">
        <hive xmlns="uri:oozie:hive-action:0.2">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
              <job-xml>lib/hive-config.xml</job-xml>
            <script>lib/impala-script.hql</script>
        </hive>
        <ok to="End"/>
        <error to="Kill"/>
    </action>
    <end name="End"/>
</workflow-app>
```

Job.properties:

```
oozie.use.system.libpath=True
security_enabled=False
dryrun=False
jobTracker=localhost:8032
nameNode=hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020
```

Comment: Any update on the above query? still the sqoop  job is killed using oozie  even if i set the property "sqoop.metastore.client.record.password" value is "true".                                                                                                         So please help me on the above query..